# how to create a JSON object from event.target.value in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

im a student working on a project and i only have a basic understanding of programming principles. its a react project that grabs live train arrivals data as a JSON obejct and then allows the user to select a arrival to a saved list.

I can get the data and display is fine with the code below,

```
getArrivals(){
fetch(`https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/${this.state.stationname}/live.json?app_id=********&app_key=**********************************&darwin=false&train_status=passenger&type=arrival`)
.then(arrivals => arrivals.json())
 .then(data => this.setState({ arrivals : data.arrivals.all }));
```

}

and display the select list with this,

```
            <form onSubmit={this.saveArrival} onChange={this.savedArrival}> 
            
            <select> value={this.state.arrivals.map(arrival => (
               <option key={arrival.origin_name} > {arrival.aimed_arrival_time} From: {arrival.origin_name} Status: {arrival.status} Expected arrival time: {arrival.expected_arrival_time}</option>
             )) }</select>  
             
            
              <p>select arrival to save</p>
              <input type='submit' />
              
              </form>
```

I can save the submitted data to a state variable called selectedArrivals however its stored as a string.
with,

```
   saveArrival = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let selArrive = JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedArrival);
  alert("You have saved arrival : " + this.state.selectedArrival);
   console.log(this.state.selectedArrival)
   }
```

and

```
  savedArrival = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
  this.setState({Schedlued_time: 
 event.target.options[selectedIndex].getAttribute('aimed_arrival_time')});
  this.setState({selectedArrival: [event.target.value]});

 }
```

I would like to have the event.target.value to be saved as a JSON object to then be sent to a cloud database. such items as "expected arrival time" should be id's so i can sort them in the database.

im sure there is a way to do it but just cant see how to achieve it. any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.